# Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app for R

Tags: r, google-analytics, rstudio, integration, analytics

I trying to import Google Analytics into R.
Everything works fine until this

```
httpuv not installed, defaulting to out-of-band authentication

Enter authorization code:
```

It brings me to this error page:
[Google error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yifJ7.png)

Comment: Maybe install the package: `install.packages("httpuv")`.

Comment: Same problem with that Google error page.

Comment: Ok, in that case it seems that you still need to enter some authorisation code somewhere.

Comment: are you using own recently created Google Cloud app credentials for OAuth process?

Comment: same here but weirdly, I did not get the error message but instead "please continue to your browser to authenticate press esc..."